# PHP DOM functuon to creat Div ID from HTML5 Elements

Tags: php, html, dom, element

I am using the following function to replace HTML5 elements with Div ID.

```
<?php function nonHTML5 ($content){
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        // Hide HTML5 element errors
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($content);
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
        // Bring elements into array
        $elements = $xp->query('//*[self::header| self::footer ]
        [not(ancestor::pre) and not(ancestor::code)]');
        // Loop through
        foreach($elements as $element){
            // Replace with 'div' tag
            $newElement = $dom->createElement('div');

            while($element->childNodes->length){
                // Keepup with the child nodes
                $childElement = $element->childNodes->item(0);
                $newElement->appendChild($dom->importNode($childElement, true));
            }
            while($element->attributes->length){
                // Mailtain the length
                $attributeNode = $element->attributes->item(0);
                $newElement->setAttributeNode($dom->importNode($attributeNode));
            }
            $element->parentNode->replaceChild($newElement, $element);
        }
    $content = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
    return $content;
} ?>
```

I know we can use HTMLShiv but I want to do this primarily for Old browsers with JavaScript disabled.

**My Challenge:**

I am not able to add an id =" " to it. For example.....

```
<header>
<h1>I am the header</h1>
</header>
```

**Should become**

```
<div id ="header">
<h1>I am the header</h1>
</div>
```

I tried doing......

```
$newElement = $dom->createElement('div id ="' . $element . '"');
```

but did not work.

**My question**

What should be the correct code?

**Please Note:** I am not a PHP expert hence please be a little descriptive in your answers / comments.

Comment: Here is the right way to do it : http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php

Comment: Let me write a proper answer if you still can't do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

**NOTE :** I have added comments for more clarification that what is happening in exactly each statement of the code.

**CREATING AN HTML ELEMENT WITH ATTRIBUTE USING DOM :**

```
<?php 

// Initiate a new DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// Create an element
$div = $dom->createElement("div","HERE DIV CONTENTS"); 

// Create an attribute i.e id
$divAttr = $dom->createAttribute('id');

// Assign value to your attribute i.e id="value"
$divAttr->value = 'This is an id';

// Add your attribute (id) to your element (div)
$div->appendChild($divAttr);

// Add your element (div) to DOM
$dom->appendChild($div);

// Print your DOM HERE
echo  $dom->saveHTML();

?>
```

**CODE OUTPUT :**

```
<div id="This is an id">HERE DIV CONTENTS</div>
```

Comment: If this solved your problem so please go ahead and accept this as answer so that the question is considered solved !